# Vue getter returns undefined when page reload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, getter

I have a blog with some posts. When you click on the preview you will redirect on the page post.
On the page of the post, I use a getter to load the correct post (I use the `find` function to return `object.name` which corresponds to the correct object in the array of objects).

```
const state = {
    ricettario: [], // data that contains all recipes (array of objects)
}

const actions = {
    // Bind State and Firestore collection
    init: firestoreAction(({ bindFirestoreRef }) => {
        bindFirestoreRef('ricettario', db.collection('____').orderBy('data'))
    })

const getters = {
    caricaRicetta(state) {
        console.log('Vuex Getter FIRED => ', state.ricettario)
        return nameParamByComponent => state.ricettario.find(ricetta => {
            return ricetta.name === nameParamByComponent
        })
    }
}
```

In the component, I call the getter in the `computed property`

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters('ricettaStore', ['caricaRicetta']),
    ricetta() {
      return this.caricaRicetta(this.slug) // this.slug is the prop of the URL (by Router)
    }
  }
```

Anything goes in the right way but when I reload the page in the POST PAGE, the getter will fire 2 times:
 1. return an error because the state is null 
 2. return the correct object 
 // screen below

[image]

**So everything works fine from the front but not at all in the console and in the App.**

I think the correct way is to call the getters in the `created` hook. What I've to change? It is a problem with the computed prop, getters or state?

POST PAGE:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="ricetta.validate === true" id="sezione-ricetta">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m10 offset-m1 l8 offset-l2">
          <img
            class="img-fluid"
            :src="ricetta.img"
            :alt="'Ricetta ' + ricetta.titolo"
            :title="ricetta.titolo"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
      ...
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you provide where are you using validate?

Comment: @mare96 Of course, I add it!

Comment: `find` obviously returns `undefined` if it finds nothing. Depends on how you want it to look like. Likely should be `v-if="ricetta && ricetta.validate"`.

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes it returns undefined because the first time the state is empty. WHY the state is empty if I sync database with state in the created hooks (in the App component) and WHY the getter runs 2 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to `validate` undifined property. So you need to check `ricetta` first.

Try like this:

```
<div v-if="ricetta && ricetta.validate === true" id="sezione-ricetta">
```

Comment: Yes, it is. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Database synchronization is asynchronous, `ricettario` is initially an empty array. Computed value is recomputed once synchronization is finished and `ricettario` array is filled, the component is updated.

Even if `ricettario` weren't empty, `find` may return `undefined` if it finds nothing. This needs to be handled where `ricetta` is used:

```
<div v-if="ricetta && ricetta.validate" id="sezione-ricetta">
```

Answer (score 0):

The error log is quite explicit, there is a `xxx.validate` somewhere in your `Ricetta` component template, but that `xxx` is undefined.

Because of this, your app crashes and stops working. I doubt it has anything to do with Vuex